# How to fix issue on tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am using a tampermonkey script but I have this error. I don't know how to fix this issue.

[image: the error displayed]
the source

```
document.onkeypress = async function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) === '=') {
        const {
            value: formValues
        } = await Swal.fire({
            title: 'Enter your credentials ',
            html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="email"
            type = "text"
            value = "kor@gmail.com" > ' +
            '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="password"
            type = "password"
            value = "A23@" > ',
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                ][![enter image description here][1]][1]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ` ... ` ;
You can search about template string in javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
document.onkeypress = async function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) === '=') {
            const {
                value: formValues
            } = await Swal.fire({
                title: 'Enter your credentials ',
                html: `<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="email" type = "text" value = "kor@gmail.com" >
                       <input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="password" type = "password" value = "A23@" > `,
                focusConfirm: false,
                preConfirm: () => {
                    return [
                        document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                        document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                    ]
                }
            })
```

Also, you can try like below;

```
html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" placeholder="email" type="text" value="kor@gmail.com"> <input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="password" type="password" value="A23@" > ',
```

Answer (score 0):

The script seems to be missing a `+` symbols ...

```
document.onkeypress = async function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) === '=') {
        const {
            value: formValues
        } = await Swal.fire({
            title: 'Enter your credentials ',
            html: '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input"' + 'placeholder="email"' 
            +'type = "text"'
            +'value = "kor@gmail.com" > ' +
            '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="password"'+
            'type = "password"'+
            'value = "A23@" > ',
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                return [
                    document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                    document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                ]
            }
        })
```

Comment: still get same error

Comment: Sorry, goofed up ... try once again ... updated my answer...

Comment: seems the first error was fixed but got anther kind of error take alook in this line '                ][![enter image description here][1]][1]'

Comment: Try removing `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` altogether